# iOS suggesting incorrect form data

Tags: ios, password, contacts, auto-complete

over the years I've accumulated a number of email addresses, some of which are used for this or that service. However, there are really two - personal and business - that I use most of the time.

I've noticed that iOS (14.4) is suggesting one of more of my arcane identities to complete an online form, rather than one of the two that I use most of the time (this occurs across all iOS devices). I've looked at my contact card, and the first two emails listed are my preferred - personal and business - yet it's selecting an email further down the list.

Can I steer Siri recommendation engine to prefer some data or otherwise delete contact information so only my preferred addresses are suggested?